# Merge custom_modul with account modul

Tags: multiple-inheritance, account, odoo-15

I want to merge my custom:modul iwth the account_accountant modul for customer invoices. I want to have some functions of my custom_modul in the form view page for customer invoices.

```
from odoo import fields, models, api


class Acc_Xinv(models.Model):
    _name = 'acc.xinv'
    _inherit = ['x.invoice', 'account.move']
        
    transaction_ids = fields.Many2many('account.move.transaction', 'transaction_channel_profile', '?', '?')


class XInvoice(models.Model):
    _name = 'x.invoice'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
    _description = "X-Invoice"
    _recname = 'name'
    _order = 'create_date desc'
    
    a lot of custom fields and custom functions: 
    ######
```

Error :
[image]

I know I have to create a new many2many field to merge my two models, but in account.move [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py) there is no transaction_ids.

My questions : What id should I put in many2many field? What does the error means, if there is no such many2many field?

Comment: Is there a many2many field in `x.invoice` using the `account.move.transaction` model (comodel_name)?

Comment: No the x.invoice modul doesnt have a relation with account.move.transaction yet at all. This custom modul doesnt depend on any other modul, until now when I wanted to put some features of the custom:modul in account modul.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Thank you very much Kenly. I have to put this on ice, so I didn't manage to continue with this.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when odoo try to create the join table using an existing table name and column names which mean you have somewhere a many2many field with the same definition.

To fix the issue try to change the relation name to something else, `xinv_transaction_channel_profile` for example